# “ActivityWatch.app“ wants access to control “System Events.app“ dialogs

Tags: macos, system-settings

I installed ActivityWatch on my Mac (OS version: Mojave), and every minute or so it launches a dialog saying “ActivityWatch.app“ wants access to control “System Events.app“.

How can I get rid of these dialogs?

Comment: The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/issues/380

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did that fixed it:

1. Quit ActivityWatch from the menu bar.
2. `sudo chown -R root:wheel /Applications/ActivityWatch.app`
3. In System Preferences / Security and Privacy / Accessibility, added ActivityWatch to list of applications authorized to control computer.
4. Restart ActivityWatch.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 seem odd. Step 3 is likely the solution and it will tell you 4 if you have the app running, no?

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain more clearly?

Comment: Skip steps 1 and 2 - they won’t help most people.

Comment: @bmike disagreed. Steps 1 and 2 are necessary. Also see here:
https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/issues/380